# WNetUseConnection blocking application in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have defined a backgroundworker which process in another thread a networkconnection and whenever it calls WNetUseConnection (in order to get access to a shared folder) it blocks completely the application, regardless if that function is running in another thread. I assume that it must be a system call which stops any task until the function returns, but I would like to know if there is any way in which I could do this whithout blocking the app

Backgroundworker code:

```
    private void Login()
    {
        if (bwWorker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            ErrorPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            bwWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void BackGroundWorkerLogin(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                        (string)Application.Current.Properties["FileSystemUserId"],
                        (string)Application.Current.Properties["FileSystemUserPassword"]);
        using (var netConnection = new NetworkConnection((string)Application.Current.Properties["FileSystemPath"], credentials))
        {
            e.Result = netConnection.ConnectionResult;
        }
    }

    private void BackGroundWorkerLoginCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)e.Result != 0)
        {

        }
    }
```

NetworkConnection code:

```
    public NetworkConnection(string netName, NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        networkName = netName;

        var netResource = new NetResource
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
            ? credentials.UserName
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

        var result = WNetUseConnection(
            IntPtr.Zero,
            netResource,
            credentials.Password,
            userName,
            0, null, null, null);

        ConnectionResult = result;
    }
```

Comment: Add the code,,,

Comment: Are you calling it in Dispatcher.Invoke by any chance?  Do add the code so we can see whats going on.

Comment: I didnt use Dispatcher.Invoke which would block the current ui, wnetuseconnection blocks the app .